# Swift Math Function from C header

Tags: swift

I'm using swift 5.0

`let a = Darwin.lgamma(0.2)`

inside `Math.h`

```
extern float lgammaf(float);
extern double lgamma(double);
extern long double lgammal(long double);
```

The compile always warns for ambigous call of `lgamma`

Comment: seems a known bug: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-8484?

Comment: Is there any workaround?

Comment: seems `lgamma(x as! Float)` is working for people

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
  internal func lgamma1<T: FloatingPoint>(_ x: T) -> T {
      switch x {
      case let d as Double:
        return lgamma(d) as Double as! T
      case let f as Float:
        return lgammaf(f) as! T
      #if arch(x86_64)
      case let lf as Float80:
        return lgammal(lf) as! T
      #endif
      default:
        return T.nan
      }
    }
```